# Geolocation in phonegap and HTML5

Tags: html, cordova, geolocation, geo

Developing a Mobile App for our County, we have a lot of trails around that people bike and hike on. Was wondering what code or functions I would need to have in my html5 so when people click the trail tab they are interested in going to it grabs there current location and then gives them directions to the trailhead. I have the GPS coordinates of the trailhead.

Any Help would be much appreciated.

Thanks Ed

Answer (score 0):

To get current location, PhoneGap provides a geolocation service.

Example:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geolocationSuccess, [geolocationError], [geolocationOptions]);
```

I suggest you look at detailed example on this page: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#Geolocation

To plot the coordinates of the trail, you can use the Google Maps API as you already have the coordinates of the trail.

Hope this helps.